# What is the mysql stop words file format?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, stop-words

Does the words have quotes or not, is it comma separated or line separated ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No quotes needed. Looking at the not-very-readable source (`ft_parser`, `ft_simple_get_word`), it seems like any non-word-character terminates a word, so you could use commas or spaces or newlines to taste.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [ft_stopword_file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_stopword_file), I believe it's simply un-quoted with a single word per line of the file.

As you're probably aware, you can browse the default compiled in set via the [Full-Text Stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) manual page.